# Curiosity: Will too much autoload in codeigniter make application slower?

Tags: php, codeigniter, autoload, autoloader

I'm using php and codeigniter, It has autoload class. 
My first question is,

```
If I use autoload class to load all model will it make my application slower? Or is there no effect?
```

My second question :

```
Which one is better and faster, loading all model you need using autoload class, Or load only some models you need in a class function?
```

Comment: one way to find out is to benchmark it and record statistical data.

Comment: codeigniter uses `eager-load` autoloading so yup, it will slow down. even ex developer of CI, phil Sturgeon wasn't happy about how the autoloading worked in CI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Autoload class will obviously make your application slower. because it uses php4 require function to load files. there are some hacks to use php 5 autoloading feature. Hope, new owner of codeigniter will add add support for autoloading.

2) It is best to use load specific models rather than autoload. in previous point I stated the reason behind this. basically it is good practice to load only the needed model, helper, library and assets. it assures that you use minimum time and memory.

Answer (score 0):

I use autoload. and its working like a charm with no significant impact on loading time.

**Method**

Add this peace of Code on top of any libraries/models that you use in you CI `autoload.php`

example for me my config/autoload.php looks like

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','door','acl','form_validation','notify');
```

and in libraries/Door.php i added

```
<?php//libraries/Door.php
function multi_auto_require($class) {
    #var_dump("requesting $class");
    if(stripos($class, 'CI') === FALSE && stripos($class, 'PEAR') === FALSE) {
        foreach (array('objects','core') as $folder){//array of folders to look inside
            if (is_file(APPPATH."{$folder}/{$class}.php")){
                include_once APPPATH."{$folder}/{$class}.php";
            }
        }
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('multi_auto_require');
class Door {
```

i added this snippet just above `class Door{` in this way this snippet will run on every time codeigniter loads door library.

**Testing and benchmarking**
now For benchmarking i tested this code in a page with 17 DB queries from 8 Autoloaded Objects from 2 different folder with array of 3 folders to look in.

**Result**
using above mentioned method Vs `include_once 'classlocation.php'` for all project classes,

the average of 10 page refreshs for both methods where around 0.6sec; 
so you can see there is no significant difference between both methods.

yet although i didn't test it on pages that doesn't use all class's, yet im sure autoloading makes my CI life much better and i'm happy with it.